# How to Use JQuery to .Click() X Pixels Away From Certain Div

Tags: jquery, html, click, position

I am using JQuery to click on a certain Div (.button) using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.create-pdf').click(function(e) {  
        $(".button").click();
        //Example: $(".button").position(x, 10px, y, 10px).click();
    });
});
```

After ".button" is clicked, I want JQuery to click again, but 10px to the right and 10px underneath the ".button" div.

Is there any code for this?

Comment: What is the element that is located 10px to the right and 10px underneath the `.button` div?  Could you just trigger a click on that element?

Comment: I have tried doing this, but if you would like to know, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283229/how-to-download-a-photo-of-canvasjs-on-submit (the ".button" is actually the 3 dotted button on the graph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work in your case ?

```
 var x = $(".button").offset();
  var xcoordinate = x.left;
  var ycoordinate = x.top;
  xcoordinate = xcoordinate +10;
  ycoordinate = ycoordinate +10;
  document.elementFromPoint(xcoordinate , ycoordinate ).click();
```

What is there at 10px to the right and 10px underneath the .button div? Is there any element? You can also give the class to that element and click using jQuery